# What are the reflective surface that can affect the skeleton joints detection by the Kinect V2?

Tags: kinect, kinect-v2

Where can I find resources about the surfaces that may affect the efficiency of skeleton tracking using Kinect v2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal experience with Kinect V2 development, only dark clothes and crowds moving behind in the background gave Kinect a hard time to maintain its efficiency, However, you can go through these labs which provides a great in-depth overview on Kinect V2 and its strong and weak points.

http://kinect.github.io/tutorial/